# How do I test a change to an sbt plugin? Resolver semantics

Tags: scala, sbt, ivy

tl;dr How do I test a change to an sbt plugin (e.g., sbt-native-packager)?

I git clone `sbt-native-packager`, tweak it, and publishLocal to `~/.ivy2/local`.

My **MWE** sbt project is like:

```
./project
./project/build.properties
./project/plugins.sbt
./project/project/build.properties
./project/project/build.sbt
```

where

both `build.properties` files say `sbt.version=0.13.15`

the `project/plugins.sbt` says

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.1.5")
```

and `project/project/build.sbt` says

```
resolvers += Resolver.file("ivy-local", file(sys.props("user.home")) / ".ivy2" / "local")(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```

But no matter how I permute things, `sbt update` always downloads the remote `sbt-native-packager` jar into `~/.ivy2/cache`
instead of getting same from `~/.ivy2/local`

Comment: Maybe, use different version for it? Like `"1.1.6-SNAPSHOT"`? Or publish it under a different name? It could be potentially disastrous if anyone could just swap implementations without notice. E.g. if you forgotten about the change, build a prod app with modified JAR and deployed it...

Comment: I would just rename it to `"version-not-on-maven-SNAPSHOT"` and call it a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I `sbt publishLocal` the plugin with `random-unique-version-SNAPSHOT` and have my main project `addSbtPlugin` that version.

Citation: @MateuszKubuszok